# Creating a variable-width gradiant fill in CSS

Tags: css

I'm currently building a WordPress theme that I would like to have a header (in the WordPress, not the HTML sense) that fits from corner to corner at the top of the page. Anchoring the far left would be an image that is filled with a solid color on its right side. Anchoring the far right would be an image that is filled with a solid color on its left side.

What I would like to do is fill the intervening space, regardless of browser width, with a gradiant that fades seamlessly from the color on its left to the color on its right. Is there a way to do this via CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the gradient as an image in [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) (one pixel high) and see http://www.cssplay.co.uk/layouts/background.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no pure-CSS way of doing that but one solution using CSS is to make a background-image of sufficient width for the largest screen width you could have and make it stretch to the current browser width.

Another way if it's all the same color is to make a background-image in GIF that is more and more transparent and set a background-color of your choice.

See [this](http://www.designdetector.com/2005/09/css-gradients-demo.php) or [this](http://www.tankedup-imaging.com/css_dev/css-gradient.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it with no images.  You can consider this to be a hack, but it gets the job done, in a way.  Adjust the number of steps in the gradient as needed.  If you want it to scale automatically to fill the window, use more `<b>` elements and don't use the border as one of the gradient steps.  Then size the `<b>` elements using percentage widths.  You can even generate the gradient using Javascript if you want to keep the download size small.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .grad b {
       display: block;
       float: left;
       width: 16px;
       height: 100%;
       border-left-width: 16px;
       border-right-width: 16px;
       border-left-style: solid;
       border-right-style: solid;
       border-left-color: #FF0000;
       background-color: #EE0011;
       border-right-color: #DD0022;
    }
    .grad b+b {
       border-left-color: #CC0033;
       background-color: #BB0044;
       border-right-color: #AA0055;
    }
    .grad b+b+b {
       border-left-color: #990066;
       background-color: #880077;
       border-right-color: #770088;
    }
    .grad b+b+b+b {
       border-left-color: #660099;
       background-color: #5500AA;
       border-right-color: #4400BB;
    }
    .grad b+b+b+b+b {
       border-left-color: #3300CC;
       background-color: #2200DD;
       border-right-color: #1100EE;
    }
    .grad b+b+b+b+b+b {
      border: none;
      background-color: #0000FF;
    }
    .grad {
      float: left;
      font-size: 100%;
      height: 30px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="grad">
      <b></b>
      <b></b>
      <b></b>
      <b></b>
      <b></b>
      <b></b>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```